# laravel eloquent model cache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am learning laravel eloquent in **Laravel 5.6**.

I have already used database query builder & cache.

**Retrieve & Store for Database Query Builder**

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function () {
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```

But i don't know how to cache for eloquent.

**Retrieve & Store for Eloquent**

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function () {
        return App\User::all();
    });
```

Is it correct for eloquent or any other method existing?

Comment: Not sure if this helps. https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-caching

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in method for this:

```
App\User::where(['id' => 1])->cache()
```

I hope this helps, although a year later.